# How to pass data correctly into React / NextJS Video component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a React based video player that is setup like this:

```
<ReactPlayer playing={true} controls={true} muted={true} loop={true} width="100" height="100" url='videos/330163_SF.mp4' poster="images/330163_C2B_Clean.png"></ReactPlayer>
```

This static URL is to be replaced with a dynamic URL coming from a data sheet:

```
const { videoID, videolink, id, thumb } = videoData
```

When put in a simple text bracket like this: **{videolink}**, the videolink is pulled and displayed correctly on the page:

```
videos/general/100004_SF.mp4
```

However, inserting and passing the data to the video component in this way does not work

```
 <ReactPlayer playing={true} controls={true} muted={true} loop={true} width="100" height="100" url={'videolink'} poster="images/330163_C2B_Clean.png"> </ReactPlayer>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your mistake is putting quotes `'` around `videolink`. Remove them and it should work.

Comment: Are u sure, that you need a quote at url prop? url={'videolink'}

Comment: @user19642323: your comment was the correct solution, the issue was with the way I have set up my data structure. Please post an answer so that I can give it the credibility it deserves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string as a prop not a variable when you inclose it in quotes

```
<ReactPlayer url={'videolink'} //This will always pass a string 
<ReactPlayer url={'videos/general/100004_SF.mp4'} //This would work for example
<ReactPlayer url={videolink} //This is the correct solution as eit t is now passing the variable.
```